# Facebook Authentication an error has occurred, try again later

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-login

I have this at the top of my page, but keep getting An error occurred. Please try again later. My app is at http://reviewsie.com. My appId is correct, copied and pasted it three times already.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
        FB.init({
            appId      : '215682891854809',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response)
    {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };

  (function(d)
{
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the fb namespace in your HTML declaration (since you are using `<fb:login-button />`?

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`

(I'm doubtful this will solve that issue but it's worth a shot.)